# Are there any Star Trek characters that are hybrids of non-human species?

Tags: star-trek, races

Hybrids are fairly common in Star Trek: [Spock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock) is half Vulcan, [Deanna Troi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deanna_Troi) is half Betazoid, [B’Elanna Torres](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B%27Elanna_Torres) is half Klingon and, just for good measure, [Simon Tarses](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Simon_Tarses) is ¼ Romulan.

However, in all of these cases that I can think of, the other half is always human.

Are there any non-human hybrid characters? Especially ones that are recurring or at least the focus of an episode?

If not, is there an out-of-universe explanation for their absence/rarity/scarcity? From a fandom point of view, I can’t imagine a half-Klingon half-Vulcan might not make for an interesting story, for example.

Comment: Do [Xindi](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Xindi) count?

Comment: An in-universe answer to the related question, *"Why are there more human/alien hybrids than alien/alien?"* could be that humans are so much more diverse than other species, so finding a compatible human (culturally/emotionally/intellectually) would be easier than most other races that are depicted in the show as being very monolithic, and in fact when alien races do diversify they often diversify so strongly that they split - such as the vulcans and romulans.  The humans appear to be one of very few races with such diversity and no splits.

Comment: @AdamDavis Did you just write that "humans are the sluts of the galaxy" in the nicest and most academic way possible?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I can neither confirm nor deny the allegations presented.

Comment: @Todd - Have you [seen the show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbKQ1LzpzeE)?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 35):

Per [Memory Alpha's article on "Hybrids"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hybrid)

> - **Betazoid / Tavnian** ([Lwaxana Troi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lwaxana_Troi)'s and [Jeyal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jeyal)'s child) (DS9: "The Muse")
> - **Cardassian / Bajoran** (Mika and [Dukat](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dukat)'s child, and Tora Ziyal) (DS9: "Covenant")
> - **Cardassian / Kazon** ([Seska](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Seska) and [Culluh](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Culluh)'s child) (VOY: "Basics, Part I", "Basics, Part II")
> - **Romulan / Klingon** (Ba'el and several other prisoners in the Carraya IV colony) (TNG: "Birthright, Part I")
> - **Romulan / Vulcan** (Saavik)
> - **Talaxian / Mylean** (Neelix's great-grandfather was Mylean) (VOY: "Scientific Method")
> - **Talaxian / Mylean / Vulcan** (Tuvix, was caused by a transporter malfunction with hybridizing flowers) (VOY: "Tuvix")
> - **Trill / Klaestron** (Benjamin Sisko briefly assumed that [Ilon Tandro](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ilon_Tandro) was the son of [Curzon Dax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Curzon_Dax) and [Enina Tandro](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Enina_Tandro)) (DS9: "Dax")

As to the scarcity of non-human hybrids, the simple fact is that the overwhelming majority of characters (especially those in committed long-term relationships where having children is likely) are human or part-human.

On top of that, many of the aliens that we see (Klingons, Romulans, Vulcans, Cardassians) view cross-species relationships, especially those that result in offspring as deeply unpleasant. While that's a fun well to dip for *adult characters*, watching children suffer isn't something that audiences want to do.

Comment: Surely, any Romulan and Vulcan offspring shouldn't count as as a hybrid of two species? They'd be mixed race, not a hybrid, no?

Comment: Although I guess that opens a whole new can of worms. On 21st century Earth what defines a species is whether members can interbreed. According to our current understanding of biology, all the main races *are the same species.*

Comment: @Shane - I'm not touching that one with a bargepole after all the downvotes I got for daring to suggest that Hermione Granger had a 'race'.

Comment: Romulans and Vulcans are from different planets.

Comment: @MrLister Romulans are the descendants of Vulcans who rejected logic and left Vulcan.

Comment: @Shane It's a trifle more complicated than just what *can* interbreed.  For example, you *can* cross lions and tigers, but nobody suggests that the two are the same species because the offspring of such a pairing is significantly different from either parent.

Comment: @Perkins Nobody suggests they are the same species because the offspring cannot reproduce itself. It has nothing to do with looks.

Comment: @Perkins, true. Lions and tiger can (fairly easily) interbreed. But the female offspring are usually infertile, and males are always sterile.

Comment: It's the same with mules.  They are almost always infertile...  But not always.  In ancient days a mule giving birth was seen as an exceedingly bad omen.  These days, modern genetic testing is threatening to completely overturn our ideas about what constitutes a "species" as we're discovering that our tree of what is related to what is full of errors and are finding that some "species" that have been known for a long time are actually true-breeding hybrids of two or more other species that live nearby.

Comment: @Shane I suggest taking a look at the [Wikipedia article on 'species'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species#Difficulty_defining_or_identifying_species): there *is no* hard-and-fast definition of species, and thus far the term defies technical specification. In addition to all the hybrids that *aren’t* (always) incapable of reproduction, there is also unicellular life, which just reproduces in such wildly different ways that the “cannot produce viable offspring” definition doesn’t even begin to make sense.

Answer (score 17):

### Yes.

You can find a full list [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hybrid).

### DS9

- [Tora Ziyal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tora_Ziyal) is a Bajoran-Cardassian hybrid.
- In the DS9 episode [*The Muse*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Muse_%28episode%29), Lwaxana Troi and her husband Jeyal have a half-Betazoid half-Tavnian child.
- In the DS9 episode [*Covenant*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Covenant_(episode)), Mika and Benyan have a half-Bajoran half-Cardassian baby.

### TNG

- *In the TNG episode* [Parallels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode))*, Worf and Deanna Troi have children who are half Klingon, one-quarter Betazoid, and only one-quarter human.* (OK, there is some human in there, but neither parent was fully human.)
- In the TNG episode [*Birthright, Part I*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Birthright,_Part_I_(episode)), Be'al and several others were Klingon-Romulan hybrids.

### Voyager

- In the VOY episode [*Scientific Method*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scientific_Method_(episode)), Neelix was a Talaxian-Mylean hybrid.
- *[Tuvix](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tuvix) was a Talaxian-Mylean-Vulcan hybrid.* (He wasn't created through ordinary means though, but by a transporter malfunction.)

### Films

- [Saavik](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saavik) was a Vulcan-Romulan hybrid.

Comment: Follow-up question: how many of these characters have you seen? ;)

Comment: Re Tuvix: I don't think transporter malfunctions count.  It sounds as if OP is looking for offspring.  But most of the other examples look good.

Comment: @OftenRight None, sorry. I'm still debating whether or not to continue watching TNG after the first season.

Comment: @Kevin True; the Worf-Troi kids are also an edge case. Perhaps I should put both in brackets or something.

Comment: @Randal'Thor the second season isn't bad, but hang in there till the third season; it really matures a lot by then 

Comment: @Randal'Thor Season 3 saw a new head writer, and Roddenberry taking a backseat, and the show's flavor changes. Most fans consider season 3 onwards clearly better than season 1 & 2. You might consider skipping the first two seasons and then revisiting them later if you want more TNG.