# Has there ever been a Vulcan/Klingon hybrid?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, vulcan

It's been confirmed in official *Star Trek* canon that various races across the Federation can copulate together. These include, to name a few, Earth and non-terrestrial humans, Khardasians, Trill hosts, Jem Hadare, the Ocampan, Romuluns, Vulcans, and Klingons. Other races, like the Ferengi, can *mate* with other humanoids, but it's unconfirmed if they  *produce offspring* there with. Matings that result in progeny often produce hybrids that combine traits of both species. Most such pairings are with a *human* and another species. Some famous examples of these characters are:

- B'Elanna Torres (*Voyager*, half-human, half-Klingon)
- Commander Tuvok (half-human, half-Vulcan)
- Deanna Troi (*TNG*, half-human, half-Betazoid)
- Sela (Romulan-human hybrid),
- Alexander Roshenko (Klingon, 1/4 human on his mother's side)
- and of course, Mr. Spock (*TOS*, part human and part Vulcan).

It's noticeably rare, however, that we see a depiction of a **dual alien** mixture. One I was most intrigued by, was the concept of a half-Vulcan, half-Klingon child. Due to how drastically different the races are, it's statistically unlikely that we'll see one on screen, but the possibility still exists. Besides that, *Star Trek* has a very long-standing, detailed and massively expansive universe in books and comics. So...

Has there ever been an official, canon or at least extended universe Vulcan-Klingon hybrid character in the *Star Trek* franchise?

If so, who is the character, how were they raised and what do they look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any Star Trek characters that are hybrids of non-human species?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131203/are-there-any-star-trek-characters-that-are-hybrids-of-non-human-species). The lack of such a combination in the answers given there suggest that no; and in any case, this earlier question would cover the answers of this one, making it a duplicate.

Comment: noted. thank you. i'll edit the question in a day,

Comment: If there were any, I'd edit them into my answer on the dupe.

Comment: Don't think Tuvok is part human